# Can I ride a triple front chainring with no front deraileruer

Tags: derailleur, chainring, derailleur-front

I've managed to strip the threads on my front deraileruer mechanism.

Its off the bike now - can I ride it as-is until I locate a new front mechanism?

The chain does stay on the front chainring where it is placed manually, while stopped. (I'd not do this while pedalling, I like counting all the way to 10 on my fingers!)

If the chain falls off the outside it will get caught on the pedal or right crankarm, and if it falls off the left its on the chain.

...now to find a three-position front derailer with top swing and bottom pull and a braze-on mount.

[image: Front Mech braze on mount]

Comment: What can I say -- it depends.  The biggest danger is if you "cross chain" severely -- most setups should be stable, but some may need to depend on the front derailer to "nudge" the chain back in place if it begins to stray.

Comment: Did you like ride the bike and test?   Why would you not post a picture of the crank and chain line rather than a missing derailleur?

Comment: Maybe it's lense distortion, but the chain already looks like it's trying to jump to the next ring. Hang the bike up on a stand and test how much cross chaining it copes with. My guess is one gear will be fine, and two lower and two higher gears will be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally a YMMV case -- some chainring+cassette+frame+rider combinations do OK with this, others really need a front derailleur/chain guide for this to work.

My suggestion to ride it without the front derailleur is to get the chain as straight as possible (put the bike on a stand, and try different gear combinations until you get the one that looks the straightest) and be smooth with your riding. This will probably be something like the middle chainring in the front and something in the middle in the back.

Comment: Surprisingly that didn't seem to make a difference.  Riding over shingle and high-speed peddling were the two things that appeared to throw the front chain, whereas being in big/big into the headwind didn't seem to make a difference.
The chainrings are quite worn, and have the odd strange munch in them so anything's possible

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although it's something that recumbent riders probably do more than upright ones. When your chainrings are something like 20T/50T/70T there's no way to shift that easily with a front derailler, so ankle shifts are often no worse than a modified FD trying to shift bigger jumps than it was made for. Cross chaining is less advisable than usual, you will tend to drop the chain especially with large chainring-large rear cogs, but most gears are usable. The ones that work least well are the ones you shouldn't be using anyway...

You can usually shift to a smaller chainring just by pausing as your ankle passes the chain and nudging it down. You will get a bit of chain grot on you from that.

Another handy trick is to sleeve a short length of poly pipe onto the drive side of the chain and tie it loosely to the chainstay. That way it'll slide along the chain while you pedal, but you have something clean to grab onto when you're shifting.

After about 6 months of that I bought a Rohloff. It seemed easier...

Answer (score 1):

OK I did a 60 km flat ride today with no front mech.  It was mostly okay when steadily pedalling into the wind.  However if the road was bumpy the chain slapped and ended up falling off the left side.

At the halfway I turned and enjoyed a moderate tailwind.  However the higher cadences and/or faster speed meant the chain fell off the pedal side, to the right.

I managed to put the chain back on about five times, while coasting.

TL,DR Yes its possible, no its not a good idea other than a "get-home" fix

EDIT: I gave up trying to fit my own replacement FD, and got the bike shop to do it just right.  They grumped at me, it was a pig of a job even with their shop full of tools.  The final fix was a combination of red locktite and a brand new claris mech (because together we'd stripped the threads on the entire shop stock of 105 triples.)   I should have got a cable tension adjuster fitted in-line, because now the cable has stretched a wee bit making up-changes difficult, and it needs a wee push by hand to get up to the big ring.   Later, this was resolved after changing to a new chain.  No idea why that had an effect.

Comment: You can get a wee plastic carbuncle to stop the chain falling off the inside, and a "chainring guard" to stop it on the outside. Or you could just buy a derailleur...

Comment: And if, as you say, the rings are badly worn, the chain is apt to catch (eg your high cadence problem) and jump off.